# permission do not allow pasting files moving files to windows

Tags: 20.04, windows-10

I have a dual boot system , windows and ubuntu however I can't move files from ubuntu to windows because of this error:
`permission do not allow pasting files`

Any help ?!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713285